# golang: cmd.Exec(): How I can read non-buffered stdout of apps?

Tags: go, subprocess, stdout

So I have the simple app which starts other apps and reads their output.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("perl", "-e", "my $x = 0; while (1) { print ++$x.qx'date'; sleep 1; }")
    stdout, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    stderr, _ := cmd.StderrPipe()

    in := bufio.NewReaderSize(io.MultiReader(stdout, stderr), 100)
    cmd.Start()
    defer cmd.Wait()
    for {
        log.Printf("....")
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        l, _ := in.ReadString('\n')
        log.Printf(string(l))
    }
}
```

The point of the real app is to read output of running process and parse it.. however it doesn't works well with real apps which don't explicitly sync/flush their stdout (it takes ~60 lines of `iperf` output before starting printing).

What is the most efficient way to read output byte-by-byte?

Comment: The Go program cannot read data from the Perl program until the Perl program flushes the data to the operating system.  Modify the Perl program to autoflush stdout using `local $| = 1;`.

Comment: @BravadaZadada I stated that `it doesn't works well with real apps`, for example - iperf3. I can't modify all apps to get byte-by-byte output. So I expected something "use `termios` package to simulate real TTY which will work like real terminal with no flush delays"

Comment: Flushing is something that can only be controlled from the writer, not the reader AFAIK. Although if you are on a system with GNU tooling you might be able to use https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html

Comment: @Evan thanks :) at least it works now

Comment: Specifics of buffering of pipes between programs tends to be OS specific. You could look to see if your OS provides an easy way to change/set this. Edit: I see @Evan mentions GNU's `stdbuf`; FreeBSD also has it's own version of [`stdbuf`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=stdbuf) that appears to have fewer restrictions.